# Animation is sticking when I drag the cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, menu, jquery-animate

I'm a super novice (I learned html, css, jQuery last week on codeAcademy) so this may be a dumb question.
However, when I drag my cursor quickly across the block in the following example the animation seems to stick, in other words, the blocks remain opaque. Could you all help me? My code it linked below. Thank you in advance.

http://jsfiddle.net/ivanjsfiddle00/eFShc/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".button").hover(function() {
    $(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({"opacity": 1 }) 
}, function() {
    $(this).filter(':not(:animated)').animate({"opacity": 0.5 })
});
});
```

**EDIT:**
Thank you all. Substituting filter(':not(:animated)') with stop(true) worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `stop()` to clear the animation queue between events. This also makes your `filter(':not(:animated)')` redundant.

```
$(".button").hover(function () {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        "opacity": 1
    })
}, function () {
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        "opacity": 0.5
    })
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/eFShc/3/)

Comment: @ivanstackoverflow00 And if you want something a bit more similar than what you had before, try to just put `.stop(true)` on the first function.

Answer (score 0):

@Rory seems to have answered the original question, but it's worth pointing out that another option would be to use CSS and make use of the `:hover` pseudo element.

```
.button {
    float: left;
    margin: 1px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #757575;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.button:hover{
    background-color:#323a44;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

detecting if the element is in animating before animate
add `if($(this).is(":animated")) return false;` before your animate code